# Count rows in a Class and select a row for a given number

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb, parse-platform, database

I'm making an iOS app using Parse.com and I wanted to knof if is there a way to retrieve the total number of rows in a class? For example, I have a "MESSAGE" class with 100 objects, is there a way to retrieve that integer like:

int x = [count MESSAGE]; //now x = 100;

And once I have 100 in my variable x I will get a random number between 1 and 100, let's say the function returns 7, is there a way to retrieve the object in row number 7?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fetch the count like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MESSAGE"];
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
  // count tells you how many objects matched the query
}];
```

You can get the 7th object like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MESSAGE"];
// Skip the first 6, retrieve the next 1
query.skip = 6;
query.limit = 1;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *messages, NSError *error) {
  // Now you have the 7th MESSAGE at messages[0]
}];
```

Putting them together, you could do:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MESSAGE"];
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
  // Skip the first <random>, retrieve the next 1
  query.skip = arc4random_uniform(count);
  query.limit = 1;
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *messages, NSError *error) {
    // Now you have a random MESSAGE at messages[0]
  }];
}];
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast and easy to understand. Seems a pretty good idea, let me try it and I'll let you know, thank you very much Ian!!

Comment: Great answer.   Could also do getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock instead of .limit = 1.